# Test Case Generation Tools

Tags: testing, frameworks

I am looking for tools or frameworks that can either generate test cases or aid in software testing.

So far I have found the following:

- Feed4JUnit (Java) - http://testful.sourceforge.net/updateSite/
- MuClipse (Java) - http://muclipse.sourceforge.net/
- MuJava (Java) - http://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/mujava/
- JTest (Java,Commercial) - http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/jtest.jsp?itemId=14
- T2 (Java) - http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/WP/T2Framework
- QuickCheck (Java/Haskell) - https://quickcheck.dev.java.net/
- Randoop (Java/.NET) - http://randoop.googlecode.com/hg/plugin/doc/index.html
- UnitCheck (Java) - http://aiya.ms.mff.cuni.cz/unitchecking/dist/
- Java Pathfinder (Java) - http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki
- UDITA (Java) - http://mir.cs.illinois.edu/udita/
- Korat (Java) - http://korat.sourceforge.net/index.html
- Fast-Code (Java) - http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/
- TestGen4J (Java) - http://sourceforge.net/projects/spike-test-gen/
  (Reported not working)
- Agitar (Java) - http://www.agitar.com/ (Comercial,ensures 80% line coverage)
- ReAssert (Java) - http://mir.cs.illinois.edu/reassert/ (Repairing Unit tests)
- Daikon (Multi-Language) - http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/daikon/ (Invariant Detector)
- Jaca (Java) - http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~eliane/JACA.html
- Pex (.NET) - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

These tools apply mostly to Java, but am also looking for .NET or other languages.

Can anyone propose other tools

Comment: It might be helpful to add the languages supported (or language agnostic).

Comment: Good idea, I have added them.

Answer (score 2):

Dotnet Testdatagenerator [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)

Answer (score 2):

**Language agnostic [all-pair testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing)**

We have used [PICT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/testing/bb980925.aspx) as a tool to successfully minimize the amount of testcases while still being reasonable confident to have most cases covered.

> the reasoning behind all-pairs testing is this: the simplest bugs in
>   a program are generally triggered by a
>   single input parameter. The next
>   simplest category of bugs consists of
>   those dependent on interactions
>   between pairs of parameters, which can
>   be caught with all-pairs testing.1
>   Bugs involving interactions between
>   three or more parameters are
>   progressively less common2, whilst at
>   the same time being progressively more
>   expensive to find by exhaustive
>   testing, which has as its limit the
>   exhaustive testing of all possible
>   inputs.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the list above, if you're looking at Pairwise (Combinatorial) test case generation, the complete, (usually) updated and an EXTENSIVE list of ALL such tools that let you generate test-cases, alongside analysis of the effectiveness of each, research papers et. al. can be found at http://www.pairwise.org/