# Generating test cases with NTestCaseBuilder (visual C#)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

For a homework assignment we are to find a test generation tool and run it on some sample code of our choice. I am having a very hard time finding an actual generator (I can find things that make unit test stubs all day, but that's not what's needed).

I have found 2: Intellitest and NTestCaseBuilder. Intellitest is only available for enterprise versions of visual studio, and unfortunately I don't have a spare 6 grand lying around, which leads me to my actual question:

How do I actually run NTestCaseBuilder? It has "ready to use" samples that I installed along with the builder itself via package manager, but I'm not sure how to actually use it. In order to install you need an existing project to include the package in, but if i just install and run in any simple default package it throws tons of errors. How do I actually run it? Is there perhaps a more basic tool for test case generation (it just needs to give some basic automated testing. Anything more than unit test stubs).

Comment: You should go back to whoever gave you your homework, and tell them it's impossible to make a tool that will automatically create tests for C#. At least if expect the generated tests to have any meaning....

Comment: It doesn't have to be c#. I am familiar with c#, python, and java, and the 2 listed were the best ones I found. Everything else was either not free or just a basic unit test (like Junit) and only gave unit test stubs. Why is it impossible though?

Comment: It's impossible to produce **meaningful** unit tests in any of these languages automatically, since they provide very little information about the code, what it's doing, and why. Some programming languages support features that allow them to be automatically tested, and verified **to a degree**. Using such languages is pretty difficult though...

Comment: you can read NTestCaseBuilder's documentation to see what it's doing: https://github.com/sageserpent-open/NTestCaseBuilder/wiki/Walk-me-through-an-example!

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747095/test-case-generation-tools